# gdb behavior when no tracepoints exist

Tags: gdb

While debugging a program using I came across a pecular behavior. I am running a process on the remote server and debug the program. For this I can use tracepoints.

I did not specify any trace point. And now when I do a tstart to start the trace experiment, it does not crib, I get he (gdb) prompt back.I did something like this:

```
(gdb) target remote 172.24.0.7:1234                                     
Remote debugging using 172.24.0.7:1234                                
0x00000000 in ?? ()                                                     
(gdb) info tra                                                        
No tracepoints.                                                       
(gdb) symbol-file /usr/local/bin/mybin1                             
Reading symbols from /usr/local/bin/ee/mybin1...done.                   
(gdb) info function  

<< list of functions from mybin1 >> 


(gdb) info tra                                                          
No tracepoints.                                                       
(gdb) tstart                                                          
(gdb)
```

I would like to know if this is an expected behavior for gdb?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since gdb 7.2 the behaviour has been to emit an error, and not start tracing.

```
(gdb) tstart
No tracepoints defined, not starting trace
(gdb)
```

The previous behaviour was to start tracing but accumulate nothing,
which seems to be what you are seeing.

http://sourceware.org/ml/gdb-patches/2010-03/msg00918.html

Comment: Thanks Matt. Your answer and the link provided solves my dilemma :). I forgot to mention the gdb version in my post which btw is 6.5